# HBase have no response to client for minutes

Tags: hbase

I have a distributed hbase cluster, with three regionserver and two tables, millions rows

Occasionally the cluster don't response to both read and write requests for about **15 minutes**, this happened several times, and last 15 minutes every time, once in about a week

I have no idea why, and find no error in logs, GC for hbase master and region server is finish in acceptable time, find no useful information after google

Can someone help me, thanks very much

My hbase version is 0.94.18 with hadoop is 1.2.1, and asynchbase 1.4.1 as client

region server log during the 15 minutes with no reponse is list blow:

```
no response 15 minutes last from 2014-08-31 20:54:45 to 2014-08-31 21:09:16
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

2014-08-31 20:41:02,488 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer: regionserver60020.periodicFlusher requesting flush for region bw,,1408098137403.4e8ffbbffd0a125b4001910affec45cc. after a delay of 7351
2014-08-31 20:41:09,841 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion: Started memstore flush for bw,,1408098137403.4e8ffbbffd0a125b4001910affec45cc., current region memstore size 94.1k
2014-08-31 20:41:09,841 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion: Finished snapshotting bw,,1408098137403.4e8ffbbffd0a125b4001910affec45cc., syncing WAL and waiting on mvcc, flushsize=96376
2014-08-31 20:41:09,841 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion: Finished snapshotting, commencing flushing stores
2014-08-31 20:41:09,845 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSUtils: Creating file=hdfs://hadoop:54310/hbase/bw/4e8ffbbffd0a125b4001910affec45cc/.tmp/97b6d77913704f56aef1d39127bea09b with permission=rwxrwxrwx
2014-08-31 20:41:09,846 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSUtils: FileSystem doesn't support getDefaultReplication
2014-08-31 20:41:09,846 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSUtils: FileSystem doesn't support getDefaultBlockSize
2014-08-31 20:41:09,879 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileWriterV2: Initialized with CacheConfig:enabled [cacheDataOnRead=true] [cacheDataOnWrite=false] [cacheIndexesOnWrite=false] [cacheBloomsOnWrite=false] [cacheEvictOnClose=false] [cacheCompressed=false]
2014-08-31 20:41:09,880 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.StoreFile: Delete Family Bloom filter type for hdfs://hadoop:54310/hbase/bw/4e8ffbbffd0a125b4001910affec45cc/.tmp/97b6d77913704f56aef1d39127bea09b: CompoundBloomFilterWriter
2014-08-31 20:41:09,909 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.StoreFile: NO General Bloom and NO DeleteFamily was added to HFile (hdfs://hadoop:54310/hbase/bw/4e8ffbbffd0a125b4001910affec45cc/.tmp/97b6d77913704f56aef1d39127bea09b)
2014-08-31 20:41:09,909 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.Store: Flushed , sequenceid=3315537, memsize=93.9k, into tmp file hdfs://hadoop:54310/hbase/bw/4e8ffbbffd0a125b4001910affec45cc/.tmp/97b6d77913704f56aef1d39127bea09b
2014-08-31 20:41:09,919 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.Store: Renaming flushed file at hdfs://hadoop:54310/hbase/bw/4e8ffbbffd0a125b4001910affec45cc/.tmp/97b6d77913704f56aef1d39127bea09b to hdfs://hadoop:54310/hbase/bw/4e8ffbbffd0a125b4001910affec45cc/a/97b6d77913704f56aef1d39127bea09b
2014-08-31 20:41:09,930 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.Store: Added hdfs://hadoop:54310/hbase/bw/4e8ffbbffd0a125b4001910affec45cc/a/97b6d77913704f56aef1d39127bea09b, entries=8, sequenceid=3315537, filesize=93.7k
2014-08-31 20:41:09,932 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion: Finished memstore flush of ~94.1k/96376, currentsize=0.0/0 for region bw,,1408098137403.4e8ffbbffd0a125b4001910affec45cc. in 91ms, sequenceid=3315537, compaction requested=false
2014-08-31 20:44:42,488 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer: regionserver60020.periodicFlusher requesting flush for region bw,01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00,1408098137403.24284ecebbdfcd95f153a46beabe0045. after a delay of 6086
2014-08-31 20:44:48,575 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion: Started memstore flush for bw,01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00,1408098137403.24284ecebbdfcd95f153a46beabe0045., current region memstore size 37.1k
2014-08-31 20:44:48,575 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion: Finished snapshotting bw,01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00,1408098137403.24284ecebbdfcd95f153a46beabe0045., syncing WAL and waiting on mvcc, flushsize=38008
2014-08-31 20:44:48,575 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion: Finished snapshotting, commencing flushing stores
2014-08-31 20:44:48,582 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSUtils: Creating file=hdfs://hadoop:54310/hbase/bw/24284ecebbdfcd95f153a46beabe0045/.tmp/f45f88b313904de49eec3f702abf811e with permission=rwxrwxrwx
2014-08-31 20:44:48,583 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSUtils: FileSystem doesn't support getDefaultReplication
2014-08-31 20:44:48,583 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSUtils: FileSystem doesn't support getDefaultBlockSize
2014-08-31 20:44:48,601 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileWriterV2: Initialized with CacheConfig:enabled [cacheDataOnRead=true] [cacheDataOnWrite=false] [cacheIndexesOnWrite=false] [cacheBloomsOnWrite=false] [cacheEvictOnClose=false] [cacheCompressed=false]
2014-08-31 20:44:48,601 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.StoreFile: Delete Family Bloom filter type for hdfs://hadoop:54310/hbase/bw/24284ecebbdfcd95f153a46beabe0045/.tmp/f45f88b313904de49eec3f702abf811e: CompoundBloomFilterWriter
2014-08-31 20:44:48,624 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.StoreFile: NO General Bloom and NO DeleteFamily was added to HFile (hdfs://hadoop:54310/hbase/bw/24284ecebbdfcd95f153a46beabe0045/.tmp/f45f88b313904de49eec3f702abf811e)
2014-08-31 20:44:48,624 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.Store: Flushed , sequenceid=3315613, memsize=36.9k, into tmp file hdfs://hadoop:54310/hbase/bw/24284ecebbdfcd95f153a46beabe0045/.tmp/f45f88b313904de49eec3f702abf811e
2014-08-31 20:44:48,632 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.Store: Renaming flushed file at hdfs://hadoop:54310/hbase/bw/24284ecebbdfcd95f153a46beabe0045/.tmp/f45f88b313904de49eec3f702abf811e to hdfs://hadoop:54310/hbase/bw/24284ecebbdfcd95f153a46beabe0045/a/f45f88b313904de49eec3f702abf811e
2014-08-31 20:44:48,650 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.Store: Added hdfs://hadoop:54310/hbase/bw/24284ecebbdfcd95f153a46beabe0045/a/f45f88b313904de49eec3f702abf811e, entries=8, sequenceid=3315613, filesize=36.6k
2014-08-31 20:44:48,652 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion: Finished memstore flush of ~37.1k/38008, currentsize=0.0/0 for region bw,01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00,1408098137403.24284ecebbdfcd95f153a46beabe0045. in 76ms, sequenceid=3315613, compaction requested=false
2014-08-31 20:45:11,191 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.LruBlockCache: Stats: total=18.95 MB, free=478.97 MB, max=497.92 MB, blocks=219, accesses=956789177, hits=956375329, hitRatio=99.95%, , cachingAccesses=956377890, cachingHits=956349801, cachingHitsRatio=99.99%, , evictions=0, evicted=26865, evictedPerRun=Infinity
2014-08-31 20:49:12,491 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer: regionserver60020.periodicFlusher requesting flush for region bw,03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00,1408098137404.b97a9d0c413fdddd8a5dc7e82ba59f7a. after a delay of 4475
2014-08-31 20:49:16,967 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion: Started memstore flush for bw,03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00,1408098137404.b97a9d0c413fdddd8a5dc7e82ba59f7a., current region memstore size 141.4k
2014-08-31 20:49:16,967 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion: Finished snapshotting bw,03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00,1408098137404.b97a9d0c413fdddd8a5dc7e82ba59f7a., syncing WAL and waiting on mvcc, flushsize=144792
2014-08-31 20:49:16,967 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion: Finished snapshotting, commencing flushing stores
2014-08-31 20:49:16,978 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSUtils: Creating file=hdfs://hadoop:54310/hbase/bw/b97a9d0c413fdddd8a5dc7e82ba59f7a/.tmp/b7b2bdd1f6384466b30a4363c2b7f22f with permission=rwxrwxrwx
2014-08-31 20:49:16,979 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSUtils: FileSystem doesn't support getDefaultReplication
2014-08-31 20:49:16,979 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSUtils: FileSystem doesn't support getDefaultBlockSize
2014-08-31 20:49:17,021 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileWriterV2: Initialized with CacheConfig:enabled [cacheDataOnRead=true] [cacheDataOnWrite=false] [cacheIndexesOnWrite=false] [cacheBloomsOnWrite=false] [cacheEvictOnClose=false] [cacheCompressed=false]
2014-08-31 20:49:17,021 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.StoreFile: Delete Family Bloom filter type for hdfs://hadoop:54310/hbase/bw/b97a9d0c413fdddd8a5dc7e82ba59f7a/.tmp/b7b2bdd1f6384466b30a4363c2b7f22f: CompoundBloomFilterWriter
2014-08-31 20:49:17,051 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.StoreFile: NO General Bloom and NO DeleteFamily was added to HFile (hdfs://hadoop:54310/hbase/bw/b97a9d0c413fdddd8a5dc7e82ba59f7a/.tmp/b7b2bdd1f6384466b30a4363c2b7f22f)
2014-08-31 20:49:17,052 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.Store: Flushed , sequenceid=3315721, memsize=141.2k, into tmp file hdfs://hadoop:54310/hbase/bw/b97a9d0c413fdddd8a5dc7e82ba59f7a/.tmp/b7b2bdd1f6384466b30a4363c2b7f22f
2014-08-31 20:49:17,060 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.Store: Renaming flushed file at hdfs://hadoop:54310/hbase/bw/b97a9d0c413fdddd8a5dc7e82ba59f7a/.tmp/b7b2bdd1f6384466b30a4363c2b7f22f to hdfs://hadoop:54310/hbase/bw/b97a9d0c413fdddd8a5dc7e82ba59f7a/a/b7b2bdd1f6384466b30a4363c2b7f22f
2014-08-31 20:49:17,071 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.Store: Added hdfs://hadoop:54310/hbase/bw/b97a9d0c413fdddd8a5dc7e82ba59f7a/a/b7b2bdd1f6384466b30a4363c2b7f22f, entries=8, sequenceid=3315721, filesize=141.0k
2014-08-31 20:49:17,073 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion: Finished memstore flush of ~141.4k/144792, currentsize=0.0/0 for region bw,03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00,1408098137404.b97a9d0c413fdddd8a5dc7e82ba59f7a. in 106ms, sequenceid=3315721, compaction requested=false
2014-08-31 20:50:11,191 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.LruBlockCache: Stats: total=18.95 MB, free=478.97 MB, max=497.92 MB, blocks=220, accesses=956969362, hits=956555513, hitRatio=99.95%, , cachingAccesses=956558075, cachingHits=956529985, cachingHitsRatio=99.99%, , evictions=0, evicted=26865, evictedPerRun=Infinity
2014-08-31 20:54:32,494 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer: regionserver60020.periodicFlusher requesting flush for region bw,04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00,1408098137404.13c8d51da8d7ff842bbc8f584843ee9f. after a delay of 21448
2014-08-31 20:54:42,494 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer: regionserver60020.periodicFlusher requesting flush for region bw,04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00,1408098137404.13c8d51da8d7ff842bbc8f584843ee9f. after a delay of 21023
2014-08-31 20:54:52,494 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer: regionserver60020.periodicFlusher requesting flush for region bw,04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00,1408098137404.13c8d51da8d7ff842bbc8f584843ee9f. after a delay of 17156
2014-08-31 20:54:53,943 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion: Started memstore flush for bw,04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00,1408098137404.13c8d51da8d7ff842bbc8f584843ee9f., current region memstore size 140.1k
2014-08-31 20:54:53,943 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion: Finished snapshotting bw,04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00,1408098137404.13c8d51da8d7ff842bbc8f584843ee9f., syncing WAL and waiting on mvcc, flushsize=143512
2014-08-31 20:54:53,943 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion: Finished snapshotting, commencing flushing stores
2014-08-31 20:54:53,948 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSUtils: Creating file=hdfs://hadoop:54310/hbase/bw/13c8d51da8d7ff842bbc8f584843ee9f/.tmp/e521dc246e6c4216bbb368f0ce98e784 with permission=rwxrwxrwx
2014-08-31 20:54:53,949 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSUtils: FileSystem doesn't support getDefaultReplication
2014-08-31 20:54:53,949 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSUtils: FileSystem doesn't support getDefaultBlockSize
2014-08-31 20:54:53,985 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileWriterV2: Initialized with CacheConfig:enabled [cacheDataOnRead=true] [cacheDataOnWrite=false] [cacheIndexesOnWrite=false] [cacheBloomsOnWrite=false] [cacheEvictOnClose=false] [cacheCompressed=false]
2014-08-31 20:54:53,985 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.StoreFile: Delete Family Bloom filter type for hdfs://hadoop:54310/hbase/bw/13c8d51da8d7ff842bbc8f584843ee9f/.tmp/e521dc246e6c4216bbb368f0ce98e784: CompoundBloomFilterWriter
2014-08-31 20:54:54,012 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.StoreFile: NO General Bloom and NO DeleteFamily was added to HFile (hdfs://hadoop:54310/hbase/bw/13c8d51da8d7ff842bbc8f584843ee9f/.tmp/e521dc246e6c4216bbb368f0ce98e784)
2014-08-31 20:54:54,012 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.Store: Flushed , sequenceid=3315851, memsize=140.0k, into tmp file hdfs://hadoop:54310/hbase/bw/13c8d51da8d7ff842bbc8f584843ee9f/.tmp/e521dc246e6c4216bbb368f0ce98e784
2014-08-31 20:54:54,021 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.Store: Renaming flushed file at hdfs://hadoop:54310/hbase/bw/13c8d51da8d7ff842bbc8f584843ee9f/.tmp/e521dc246e6c4216bbb368f0ce98e784 to hdfs://hadoop:54310/hbase/bw/13c8d51da8d7ff842bbc8f584843ee9f/a/e521dc246e6c4216bbb368f0ce98e784
2014-08-31 20:54:54,032 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.Store: Added hdfs://hadoop:54310/hbase/bw/13c8d51da8d7ff842bbc8f584843ee9f/a/e521dc246e6c4216bbb368f0ce98e784, entries=8, sequenceid=3315851, filesize=139.7k
2014-08-31 20:54:54,034 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion: Finished memstore flush of ~140.1k/143512, currentsize=0.0/0 for region bw,04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00,1408098137404.13c8d51da8d7ff842bbc8f584843ee9f. in 91ms, sequenceid=3315851, compaction requested=false
2014-08-31 20:55:11,191 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.LruBlockCache: Stats: total=18.95 MB, free=478.97 MB, max=497.92 MB, blocks=221, accesses=957103402, hits=956689552, hitRatio=99.95%, , cachingAccesses=956692115, cachingHits=956664024, cachingHitsRatio=99.99%, , evictions=0, evicted=26865, evictedPerRun=Infinity
2014-08-31 20:56:27,483 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer: Scanner 2176807346167982283 lease expired on region messages,07\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00,1402123407978.1a34b2e385e39cf3a82ae55f732c7a4e.
.......................
2014-08-31 20:56:38,174 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer: Scanner -6933263087733055502 lease expired on region messages,11\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00,1402123407978.198c072806a86f7103a0f3c6de11290a.
2014-08-31 20:56:38,174 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer: Scanner -2230372302736915424 lease expired on region messages,08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00,1402123407978.3ab90beebbc002e19a2f024cb74e5e99.
2014-08-31 20:59:55,789 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.Store: Skipping major compaction of info because one (major) compacted file only and oldestTime 7395388096ms is < ttl=9223372036854775807
2014-08-31 21:00:11,191 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.LruBlockCache: Stats: total=19.41 MB, free=478.52 MB, max=497.92 MB, blocks=229, accesses=957113714, hits=956699856, hitRatio=99.95%, , cachingAccesses=956702427, cachingHits=956674328, cachingHitsRatio=99.99%, , evictions=0, evicted=26865, evictedPerRun=Infinity
2014-08-31 21:09:41,115 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer: Client tried to access missing scanner -5479515347986367613
.......................
2014-08-31 21:10:11,191 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.LruBlockCache: Stats: total=19.41 MB, free=478.52 MB, max=497.92 MB, blocks=229, accesses=957150432, hits=956736574, hitRatio=99.95%, , cachingAccesses=956739145, cachingHits=956711046, cachingHitsRatio=99.99%, , evictions=0, evicted=26865, evictedPerRun=Infinity
2014-08-31 21:10:41,126 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer: Scanner 2475283676294571093 lease expired on region messages,07\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00,1402123407978.1a34b2e385e39cf3a82ae55f732c7a4e.
.........................
2014-08-31 21:10:41,127 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer: Scanner -1230151222882130492 lease expired on region messages,05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00,1402123407977.d364a5f6bc7e54e72d915a3198636afd.
2014-08-31 21:10:41,127 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer: Scanner -3189762669648092281 lease expired on region 
...............
2014-08-31 21:10:41,731 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer: Scanner 4766251358165302168 lease expired on region messages,05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00,1402123407977.d364a5f6bc7e54e72d915a3198636afd.
2014-08-31 21:15:11,191 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.LruBlockCache: Stats: total=19.41 MB, free=478.52 MB, max=497.92 MB, blocks=229, accesses=957331387, hits=956917529, hitRatio=99.95%, , cachingAccesses=956920100, cachingHits=956892001, cachingHitsRatio=99.99%, , evictions=0, evicted=26865, evictedPerRun=Infinity
2014-08-31 21:16:32,506 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer: regionserver60020.periodicFlusher requesting flush for region messages,05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00,1402123407977.d364a5f6bc7e54e72d915a3198636afd. after a delay of 5644
2014-08-31 21:16:32,506 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer: regionserver60020.periodicFlusher requesting flush for region messages,05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00,1402123407977.d364a5f6bc7e54e72d915a3198636afd., current region memstore size 195.8k
2014-08-31 21:16:38,151 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion: Finished snapshotting 
2014-08-31 21:16:38,156 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSUtils: Creating file=hdfs://hadoop:54310/hbase/messages/d364a5f6bc7e54e72d915a3198636afd/.tmp/67548981c14c48abbdd66208436e150a with permission=rwxrwxrwx
2014-08-31 21:16:38,157 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSUtils: FileSystem doesn't support getDefaultReplication
2014-08-31 21:16:38,157 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSUtils: FileSystem doesn't support getDefaultBlockSize
2014-08-31 21:16:38,165 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileWriterV2: Initialized with CacheConfig:enabled [cacheDataOnRead=true] [cacheDataOnWrite=false] [cacheIndexesOnWrite=false] [cacheBloomsOnWrite=false] [cacheEvictOnClose=false] [cacheCompressed=false]
2014-08-31 21:16:38,166 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.StoreFile: Delete Family Bloom filter type for hdfs://hadoop:54310/hbase/messages/d364a5f6bc7e54e72d915a3198636afd/.tmp/67548981c14c48abbdd66208436e150a: CompoundBloomFilterWriter
2014-08-31 21:16:38,188 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.StoreFile: NO General Bloom and NO DeleteFamily was added to HFile (hdfs://hadoop:54310/hbase/messages/d364a5f6bc7e54e72d915a3198636afd/.tmp/67548981c14c48abbdd66208436e150a)
2014-08-31 21:16:38,189 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.Store: Flushed , sequenceid=3316344, memsize=180.3k, into tmp file hdfs://hadoop:54310/hbase/messages/d364a5f6bc7e54e72d915a3198636afd/.tmp/67548981c14c48abbdd66208436e150a
2014-08-31 21:16:38,197 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.Store: Renaming flushed file at hdfs://hadoop:54310/hbase/messages/d364a5f6bc7e54e72d915a3198636afd/.tmp/67548981c14c48abbdd66208436e150a to hdfs://hadoop:54310/hbase/messages/d364a5f6bc7e54e72d915a3198636afd/a/67548981c14c48abbdd66208436e150a
2014-08-31 21:16:38,208 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.Store: Added hdfs://hadoop:54310/hbase/messages/d364a5f6bc7e54e72d915a3198636afd/a/67548981c14c48abbdd66208436e150a, entries=580, sequenceid=3316344, filesize=106.7k
2014-08-31 21:16:38,210 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion: Finished memstore flush of ~195.8k/200488, currentsize=0.0/0 for region messages,05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00,1402123407977.d364a5f6bc7e54e72d915a3198636afd. in 59ms, sequenceid=3316344, compaction requested=true
2014-08-31 21:16:38,210 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.Store: d364a5f6bc7e54e72d915a3198636afd - a: Initiating minorcompaction
2014-08-31 21:16:38,222 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion: Starting compaction on a in region messages,05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00,1402123407977.d364a5f6bc7e54e72d915a3198636afd.
2014-08-31 21:16:38,222 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.Store: Starting compaction of 3 file(s) in a of messages,05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00,1402123407977.d364a5f6bc7e54e72d915a3198636afd. into tmpdir=hdfs://hadoop:54310/hbase/messages/d364a5f6bc7e54e72d915a3198636afd/.tmp, seqid=3316344, totalSize=4.0m
2014-08-31 21:16:38,222 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion: Starting compaction on a in region messages,05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00,1402123407977.d364a5f6bc7e54e72d915a3198636afd.
2014-08-31 21:16:38,222 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.Store: Starting compaction of 3 file(s) in a of messages,05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00,1402123407977.d364a5f6bc7e54e72d915a3198636afd. into tmpdir=hdfs://hadoop:54310/hbase/messages/d364a5f6bc7e54e72d915a3198636afd/.tmp, seqid=3316344, totalSize=4.0m
2014-08-31 21:16:38,222 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.Compactor: Compacting hdfs://hadoop:54310/hbase/messages/d364a5f6bc7e54e72d915a3198636afd/a/6f8d2fc1160245318ddec3f193982d9c, keycount=7820, bloomtype=NONE, size=3.6m, encoding=NONE
2014-08-31 21:16:38,223 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.Compactor: Compacting hdfs://hadoop:54310/hbase/messages/d364a5f6bc7e54e72d915a3198636afd/a/75cb807d466940d98acc15ad295d374b, keycount=592, bloomtype=NONE, size=250.5k, encoding=NONE
2014-08-31 21:16:38,223 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.Compactor: Compacting hdfs://hadoop:54310/hbase/messages/d364a5f6bc7e54e72d915a3198636afd/a/67548981c14c48abbdd66208436e150a, keycount=580, bloomtype=NONE, size=106.7k, encoding=NONE
2014-08-31 21:16:38,223 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.CompactSplitThread: Small Compaction requested: regionName=messages,05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00,1402123407977.d364a5f6bc7e54e72d915a3198636afd., storeName=a, fileCount=3, fileSize=4.0m (3.6m, 250.5k, 106.7k), priority=3, time=7733965975674385; Because: regionserver60020.cacheFlusher; compaction_queue=(0:0), split_queue=0
2014-08-31 21:16:38,224 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSUtils: Creating file=hdfs://hadoop:54310/hbase/messages/d364a5f6bc7e54e72d915a3198636afd/.tmp/0cfab02d23184841b0185dbcb3c7cb21 with permission=rwxrwxrwx
2014-08-31 21:16:38,225 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSUtils: FileSystem doesn't support getDefaultReplication
2014-08-31 21:16:38,225 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSUtils: FileSystem doesn't support getDefaultBlockSize
2014-08-31 21:16:38,229 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileWriterV2: Initialized with CacheConfig:enabled [cacheDataOnRead=true] [cacheDataOnWrite=false] [cacheIndexesOnWrite=false] [cacheBloomsOnWrite=false] [cacheEvictOnClose=false] [cacheCompressed=false]
2014-08-31 21:16:38,229 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.StoreFile: Delete Family Bloom filter type for hdfs://hadoop:54310/hbase/messages/d364a5f6bc7e54e72d915a3198636afd/.tmp/0cfab02d23184841b0185dbcb3c7cb21: CompoundBloomFilterWriter
2014-08-31 21:16:38,383 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.StoreFile: NO General Bloom and NO DeleteFamily was added to HFile (hdfs://hadoop:54310/hbase/messages/d364a5f6bc7e54e72d915a3198636afd/.tmp/0cfab02d23184841b0185dbcb3c7cb21)
2014-08-31 21:16:38,396 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.Store: Renaming compacted file at hdfs://hadoop:54310/hbase/messages/d364a5f6bc7e54e72d915a3198636afd/.tmp/0cfab02d23184841b0185dbcb3c7cb21 to hdfs://hadoop:54310/hbase/messages/d364a5f6bc7e54e72d915a3198636afd/a/0cfab02d23184841b0185dbcb3c7cb21
2014-08-31 21:16:38,406 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.Store: Removing store files after compaction...
2014-08-31 21:16:38,409 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.backup.HFileArchiver: Archiving compacted store files.
2014-08-31 21:16:38,410 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.backup.HFileArchiver: Starting to archive files:[class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.backup.HFileArchiver$FileableStoreFile, ..........................................
for:hdfs://hadoop:54310/hbase/.archive/messages/d364a5f6bc7e54e72d915a3198636afd/a/75cb807d466940d98acc15ad295d374b, free to archive original file.
2014-08-31 21:16:38,419 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.backup.HFileArchiver: Finished archiving file from: class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.backup.HFileArchiver$FileableStoreFile, file:hdfs://hadoop:54310/hbase/messages/d364a5f6bc7e54e72d915a3198636afd/a/75cb807d466940d98acc15ad295d374b, to: hdfs://hadoop:54310/hbase/.archive/messages/d364a5f6bc7e54e72d915a3198636afd/a/75cb807d466940d98acc15ad295d374b
2014-08-31 21:16:38,419 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.backup.HFileArchiver: Archiving:class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.backup.HFileArchiver$FileableStoreFile, file:hdfs://hadoop:54310/hbase/messages/d364a5f6bc7e54e72d915a3198636afd/a/67548981c14c48abbdd66208436e150a
2014-08-31 21:16:38,420 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.backup.HFileArchiver: No existing file in archive for:hdfs://hadoop:54310/hbase/.archive/messages/d364a5f6bc7e54e72d915a3198636afd/a/67548981c14c48abbdd66208436e150a, free to archive original file.
2014-08-31 21:16:38,423 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.backup.HFileArchiver: Finished archiving file from: class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.backup.HFileArchiver$FileableStoreFile, file:hdfs://hadoop:54310/hbase/messages/d364a5f6bc7e54e72d915a3198636afd/a/67548981c14c48abbdd66208436e150a, to: hdfs://hadoop:54310/hbase/.archive/messages/d364a5f6bc7e54e72d915a3198636afd/a/67548981c14c48abbdd66208436e150a
2014-08-31 21:16:38,423 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.Store: Completed compaction of 3 file(s) in a of messages,05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00,1402123407977.d364a5f6bc7e54e72d915a3198636afd. into 0cfab02d23184841b0185dbcb3c7cb21, size=4.0m; total size for store is 332.2m
2014-08-31 21:16:38,423 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.compactions.CompactionRequest: completed compaction: regionName=messages,05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00,1402123407977.d364a5f6bc7e54e72d915a3198636afd., storeName=a, fileCount=3, fileSize=4.0m, priority=3, time=7733965975674385; duration=0sec
2014-08-31 21:16:38,424 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.compactions.CompactionRequest: CompactSplitThread status: compaction_queue=(0:0), split_queue=0
2014-08-31 21:16:40,082 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion: Started memstore flush for messages,03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00,1402123407977.5d9b973aef7e10eee0e32fecdbeb37e9., current region memstore size 245.3k
2014-08-31 21:16:40,083 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion: Finished snapshotting messages,03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00,1402123407977.5d9b973aef7e10eee0e32fecdbeb37e9., syncing WAL and waiting on mvcc, flushsize=251224
2014-08-31 21:16:40,083 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion: Finished snapshotting, commencing flushing stores
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing the following things

Run `jstat` to see if  LONG GC pause is happening .

```
sudo -u username jstat -gc pid
sudo -u username jmap -histo:live pid
```

The following set of logs:

```
2014-08-31 20:56:38,174 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer: Scanner -6933263087733055502 lease expired on region messages,11\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00,1402123407978.198c072806a86f7103a0f3c6de11290a.
2014-08-31 20:56:38,174 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer: Scanner -2230372302736915424 lease expired on region messages,08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00,1402123407978.3ab90beebbc002e19a2f024cb74e5e99.
2014-08-31 20:59:55,789 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.Store: Skipping major compaction of info because one (major) compacted file only and oldestTime 7395388096ms is < ttl=9223372036854775807
2014-08-31 21:00:11,191 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.LruBlockCache: Stats: total=19.41 MB, free=478.52 MB, max=497.92 MB, blocks=229, accesses=957113714, hits=956699856, hitRatio=99.95%, , cachingAccesses=956702427, cachingHits=956674328, cachingHitsRatio=99.99%, , evictions=0, evicted=26865, e victedPerRun=Infinity
2014-08-31 21:09:41,115 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer: Client tried to access missing scanner -5479515347986367613
```

Clearly shows Hbase block cache is being Churned due to reads (scan is what you are performing).

Please disable setblockCache(false) in case you are using MR to scan your table .